# Excel: Provide a split range as one input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

Normally in Excel, if I wanted to input a range into a function I would use `C8:D13` But what If I split the rows with a row in between, but still wanted that range. So it would be `C8:C13` + `E8:E13`?

But how can one insert this as a single range?

Comment: It really is function dependent if you can use a non-continious (e.g. multiple ranges) reference. Those that do support it, mostly expect equal sized ranges. What exactly are your trying to do here? Maybe this could be a x-y problem?

Comment: Unfortunately its a 3rd party addin so i cant send the function. but effectively it takes a range that kind of represents a dictionary, where the left hand side is the key, and the right hand side is the values, so it think it needs to stay together

Comment: Well, without a [mcve] I wouldn't know how to advise you on the matter. If the add-in accepts arrays, maybe you could use VBA to return an array excluding the specific row/column.

Comment: why not just do =C8 in F1, and drag until F6, then =E8 in F7 and drag until F12 . Then use F1:F12 as input instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Excel cannot directly concatenate arrays in the way you describe (i.e.
>   simply combining them back to back.) However, there is a (complicated)
>   solution to this problem without using helper functions.

You can check out [the rest of the details here](http://Excel%20cannot%20directly%20concatenate%20arrays%20in%20the%20way%20you%20describe%20(i.e.%20simply%20combining%20them%20back%20to%20back.)%20However,%20there%20is%20a%20(complicated)%20solution%20to%20this%20problem%20without%20using%20helper%20functions.).

Without knowing more about the problem, it's hard to give an appropriate solution. However, you may look into using `TEXTJOIN()` with a comma for a delimiter, and set `ignore blanks` as `TRUE`, then split the comma-seperated values again.

Answer (score 0):

Some formulas may work differently, but for most, it's quite simple:

Original range:
`=SUM(C8:D13)`

After inserting a column (automatically updates):
`=SUM(C8:E13)`

Manual correction to ignore new column:
`=SUM(C8:C13,E8:E13)`